Unverified token DADDY
I did a swap a few months ago from SOL to DADDY. Now when I log onto my phantom wallet, the wallet is saying that the 'token is hidden because Phantom believes it is spam'. The Phantom wallet is giving the option to click to "Report as not spam", but I wanted to ask the community, how do I check?
I believe I grabbed the address in order to swap from coinmarketcap so it was a reliable source.
The transaction on SOLSCAN is here - https://solscan.io/tx/37woYiQcbbjPV4fy6XwcarWN1FosyLTAf4h8RTaykYV7kDAacYLhqZsn3RjCvixNecfazFzSXgm4UXVBFgmQWux7
Any help is appreciated
